# Jquery datatable I can't display the 'export' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to to add some buttons 'export' but any one of them appear on screen..

**CSS link** :

```html
<link href="/Datatable/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Datatable/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Datatable/media/css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Datatable/media/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Datatable/media/css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Datatable/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Datatable/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://datatables.net/media/css/jui_themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**JS Link** :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Datatable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "700px",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 50
    }, {
        "aoColumns": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {
            "sType": "currency-pre"
        }]
    }, {
        "sDom": '&lt;"H"Tfr>t&lt;"F"ip>',
            "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_x‌​ls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": ["copy", "print"]
        }
    }).columnFilter();
});
```

I don't understand what I do wrong...

Comment: @cosset: formating completed, now pls answer :)

Comment: post your error, which is their in browser consle

Comment: that's the problem, I don't see one ! ...